# R - waffle package error "panel.spacing" is not a valid theme element name

Tags: r, waffle-chart

Im trying to use the package waffle in R and it seems to be giving me the following error. I've copied this code from the GitHub [repository](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/waffle/tree/cran) of the package.

```
library(waffle)
parts <- c(80, 30, 20, 10)
waffle(parts, rows=8)

Error in (function (el, elname)  : 
  "panel.spacing" is not a valid theme element name.
```

Any idea what this could be?

Comment: Are you using the latest version from CRAN? I just confirmed that this code works for me.

Comment: Just for a super quick reply from the creator. Turns out my ggplot2 was out of date.

Answer (score 0):

What is your version of ggplot2? 
Take a look using sessionInfo().

I believe panel.spacing has only become a parameter for themes in later versions of ggplot2 (see, for instance, https://github.com/jrnold/ggthemes/issues/73).

Try updating ggplot2 version.